# A special function for uids

Tags: python, hash, uuid, hashcode, uid

I have an unique identifier (uid) `x`, and given an integer `j`, I need a function `f` such that `f(x, j)` is another uid (in the same "domain" as `x`) such that `f(x, j1) = f(x, j2)` if and only if `j1 = j2` and `f(x, j) != x` for any `j`.
A naive way to do this is to maintain `x` as a tuple `(i1, i2, ..., ik)` and define `f(x, j) = (j, i1, i2, ..., ik)`. Is there a better, more efficient way to do this? I am specifically looking for python solutions.

Edit: I also need `f(x1, j1) = f(x2, j2)` if and only if `x1 = x2` and `j1 = j2`

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that `j` is never zero, then the function you're looking for is simply called [*exclusive-or*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

```
def f(x, j):
    return x ^ j
```

Assume the type of unique identifiers `x` is `int`. The exclusive-or operator forms a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) on Python integers, with `0` as the identity. Hence, as long as `j != 0`, we have `x ^ j != x`. And since exclusive-or forms a group, we can cancel off the `x`. Suppose `x ^ j1 == x ^ j2`. Then `x ^ x ^ j1 = x ^ x ^ j2`, and the exclusive-or of a value with itself is zero, so `0 ^ j1 = 0 ^ j2`, hence `j1 = j2`.

You need `j != 0`, since zero is the identity of this operation.

---

**Edit:** In response to your further condition that `f(x1, j1) = f(x2, j2)` implies `x1 = x2` and `j1 = j2`, I think you're stuck with what you already found (appending to the end of a tuple). That's a very powerful condition, and I think at that point you've basically got a free monoid. So I don't see a way to do better than simple linear concatenation.

Comment: I have edited the question to include one more condition that isn't satisfied by XOR: for example, `f(4, 4) = f(3, 3) = 0`. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @helperFunction No worries! Unfortunately, that's a *very* powerful condition, and I think that if you really need that strong level of uniqueness, you're stuck doing what you've already figured out: concatenating at the end of a tuple. I don't think there's any clever mathematical tricks that will get you something that powerful in less space.